# How Can I Prevent Windows From Jumbling my Open Windows to Different Screens When Switching Between Users

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, user-accounts, user-switching

I windows 7, I have several screens connected to my desktop.

When I switch users and resume my session with my current user login, my windows are jumbled around randomly to different screens.

Is there a way to prevent this?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [UltraMon](http://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/)?  I haven't run into the problem you describe, but I know UltraMon makes the multi-monitor experience a lot nicer in general.

Comment: Spot on - Ultramon is the tool I would have suggested too. I've used `free` alternatives, but nothing as easy to use as Ultramon in a multi-monitor setup.